# How can I move certain words/phrases in the title of a Lilypond score vertically?

Tags: lilypond

In the title section of a Lilypond score, I would like a certain word to be placed further down than the rest of the text (in my specific case, I'm using a font for a certain word where the font makes it look like the word is placed higher up than the other words).

```
title = \markup
    {
        "I want"
        "THIS"
        "word to be further down"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a *raise* keyword that might do the trick:

```
\markup {
  C
  \small
  \bold
  \raise #1.0
  9/7+
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! I used it together with negative values to *lower* the text.